# Object creation in static method is changing private member variables of other static object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, static-methods

To give a simple example of the problem I am having, consider a class that creates a link(like in a chain). Each link has a parent link except for the root link. The parent link of the root link is null.

```cpp
#ifndef LINK_HPP
#define LINK_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <string>

//Link.hpp
class Link
{
    public:
        Link(const std::string &linkName, const Link *parentLink);
        Link(const std::string &linkName);
        const Link* getParentLink();
        ~Link();
        static Link* createRootLink(const std::string &linkName);
        static Link* getRootLink();

    private:
        std::string linkName;
        const Link *parentLink;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
#include "Link.hpp"

Link* Link::createRootLink(const std::string &linkName)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Link> rootLink(new Link(linkName));
    return rootLink.get();
}

Link::Link(const std::string &linkName)
{
    this->linkName = linkName;
    this->parentLink = nullptr;
}

Link::Link(const std::string &linkName, const Link* parentLink)
{
    this->linkName = linkName;
    this->parentLink = parentLink;
}

Link::~Link()
{

}

const Link* Link::getParentLink()
{
    return this->parentLink;
}
```

In unit testing my code, I have created a helper class which defines functions useful for the testing. In HelperClass.hpp there is a static method that creates a shared pointer to a link and returns the raw pointer. Keep in mind this helper function is merely to reproduce a problem. I understand the method is kinda useless.

```cpp
#include "Link.hpp"

class HelperClass
{
    public:
        static Link* createALink(const std::string &linkName, Link*     parentLink)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Link> link(new Link(linkName, parentLink));

            return link.get();
        }
};
```

Alright now for the actual test that shows where the problem is.

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Link.hpp"
#include "HelperClass.hpp"

class ReferenceFrameTest : public ::testing::Test
{
    protected:

        virtual void SetUp()
        {
        }
        virtual void TearDown()
        {
        }

        Link* rootLink = Link::createRootLink("root");
        // Why does this call right here change the parentLink of rootLink!!
        Link* link1 = HelperClass::createALink("link1", rootLink);

    private:

};

TEST_F(ReferenceFrameTest, testRootLinkHasNullParent)
{
    // the parent link of rootLink should be nullptr or 0
    // this currently outputs 0x264f960
    std::cout << rootLink->getParentLink() << std::endl;

    // This fails if I create the Link* from HelperClass.hpp
    ASSERT_FALSE(rootLink->getParentLink());
}
```

The act of creating the pointer to a Link in `HelperClass` somehow is changing the `parentLink` of `rootLink`. Note that if instead I just instantiate a new Link on the stack, the `parentLink` of `rootLink` remains `nullptr` as it should. What am I missing here? Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createRootLink` returns a dangling pointer.

```
Link* Link::createRootLink(const std::string &linkName)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Link> rootLink(new Link(linkName));
    return rootLink.get();
}
```

The `unique_ptr` deletes its object when it goes out of scope, which is at the end of the `createRootLink` function.  So that memory can be reused, or all sorts of other undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah ok I think I think I see. How can I fix this so that I can create multiple chains each having their own root link and avoid the dangling pointer?

Comment: You could have `createRootLink` return `std::unique_ptr<Link>`.  This transfers responsibility for eventual cleanup to the caller.